# flutter: how to make a listview update without pressing a button?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, listview, widget

so I'm currently working on an application that has a listview on the first screen (implemented on main.dart).
The listview fetches it's data from internet (async).
The problem is that, the listview does not get updated when the data is changed.

(I can implement this functionality simply by designing a 'reload' button and pressing it every time I want the new data. But that's not what I want right now).

In other words, how can I update the listview automatically?

**EDIT1: ADDING SOME CODE**
code might be messy; see the description at the end.

```
class RssFeed extends StatelessWidget {
  String title;
  String pubDate;
  RssFeed(this.title, this.pubDate);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: Text(title),
          ),
          Text(pubDate)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FeedsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {

    return _FeedsListState();
  }
}

class _FeedsListState extends State<FeedsList> {
  List<Widget> list1 = new List<Widget>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    ls();
  }

  Future ls() async {
    list1.clear();
    list.clear();
    sites1.clear();
    RSS_reader rss_reader = new RSS_reader();
    for (var i in saver.list.items) {
      sites1.add(
          site(siteAdress: i.siteAdress, siteDescription: i.siteDescription));
    }
    var res = await rss_reader.Get_items(sites1);

    for (var val in res) {
      list.add(InkWell(
          onTap: () => _launchURL(val.item.link),
          child: Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[100],
            child: Center(
              child: new RssFeed(val.item.title, val.item.pubDate.toString()),
            ),
          )));
    }
    print(list.length);
    setState(() {
      list1 = list;
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: list1.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
              return list1[i];
            }));
  }
}
```

**DESCRIPTION:**
As you can guess, this is a RSS reader.
So, I have a class RSSFeed; which makes one of the tiles of Listview.
then in the FeedsList class (stateful widget), I make the listview.
I have a class called RSS_reader and a method Get_items, which gets a bunch of sites as input and puts those sites' newest feeds in a list ('res' in the above code).
Then, I put the items in a list of 'Container's and then build the listview.

Then, in the main function, I create a container like below:
Container(
height: 500,
width: 580,
child: FeedsList(),
)
and there appears the problem; the FeedsList class does not get updated automatically. although if I put a button and navigate to FeedsList class through that button, the list is refreshed and OK.

Thanks for reading and help.

Comment: Can you add some code? there's many ways to do that

Comment: @JonathanIxcayau Added! though, I hope it's not too messy to read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to fetch data once from your external source use a FutureBuilder, if you want to fetch data multiple times take a look to StreamBuilder. Both widgets will have the behavior you are looking for, with no refresh button.

Simple example of how to use a FutureBuilder:

```
Future<List<String>> _fetchData() {
    return // fetch data from source
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _fetchData,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapshot) {
          
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                // This widget will be built when data is fetched
                const List<String> list = snapshot.data; 
                return ListView(
                    children: list.map(
                        (element) => ListTile(
                            title: Text(element),
                        ),
                    ).asList(),
                );
            } else {
                // This widget will be built while you are waiting for your data to be fetched
                return Container(
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text("Loading data..."),
                    ),
                );
            }
        },
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll look into streambuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to stream data and ListView will update automatically.

Answer (score 0):

In the button that you say you can re call your ls() functions, your list should update on tap button

sample:

```
return Scaffold(
    body: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: list1.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        return list1[i];
      },
    ),
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
      onPressed: () => ls(),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: This should refresh your list everytime you tap fab

Comment: Yes! Though, as I said, I don't want to tap on the button. Thanks very much for your reply.